# Getting SQL error "Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value

Tags: mysql

I am running a SQL update statement where I have to replace a column with datatype longtext with a JSON value where previously some other JSON was there

Present value:-

```
          {
          "ChangePasswordQry": ["SET PASSWORD FOR '${accountName}'@'%' = 
           PASSWORD('${randomPassword}')", 
           "FLUSH PRIVILEGES"]
           }
```

To be updated :

```
      {
       "ChangePasswordQry":
       ["SET PASSWORD FOR '${accountName}'@'%' = CONCAT('*', 
        UPPER(SHA1(UNHEX(SHA1('${randomPassword}')))))", 
      "FLUSH PRIVILEGES"]
       }
```

My Query:-

```
   update test_database
   SET JSONVALUE = 
        '{\n    \"ChangePasswordQry\": [\"SET PASSWORD FOR 
   \'${accountName}\'@\'%\' = CONCAT('*', UPPER(SHA1(UNHEX(SHA1(\'${randomPassword}\')))))\", 
   \"FLUSH PRIVILEGES\"]\n}\n'
   WHERE STUDENTATTRIBUTEKEY='CHANGEPASSJSON' and STUDENTNAME ='STUDENT123';
```

**Getting the exception:-Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '{"ChangePasswordQry": ["SET PASSWORD FOR '${accountName}'@'%' = CONCAT('**

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
    update test_database
    SET JSONVALUE = 
    '{\n    \"ChangePasswordQry\": [\"SET PASSWORD FOR 
      \'${accountName}\'@\'%\' = CONCAT(\'*\', 
       UPPER(SHA1(UNHEX(SHA1(\'${randomPassword}\')))))\", 
       \"FLUSH PRIVILEGES\"]\n}\n'
     WHERE STUDENTATTRIBUTEKEY='CHANGEPASSJSON' and STUDENTNAME ='STUDENT123';
```